# Visual Studio 2010 Missing HTML5 Video?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html, html5-video

Working with HTML5 within VS2010, I don't understand how the source tags aquire the path for the video. I assume it either can be Absoulute or Relative.

What I am attempting is very simple:

```
<video id="my_video" width="480" height="300" controls preload="none" poster="webm/art_leaf_resized.jpg">
        <source src="webm/Along_the_Path.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="webm/Along the Path.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="webm/Along the Path.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

However, Pressing F5 in VS2010, Firefox and IE9 can not locate the video displaying an X. Chrome is able to find the video and play it.

**The poster image shows correctly and isn't missing. The poster image is in the same directory as the videos?**

File Directory:

[image]

A basic HTML page **(HTMLPage1.htm)** holds only the video element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="my_video" width="480" height="300" controls
        preload="none" poster="webm/art_leaf_resized.jpg">
    <source src="webm/Along_the_Path.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="webm/Along the Path.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="webm/Along the Path.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Closing VS2010 and opening IE9 and dragging in the htm page, the video is able to play in IE9, Firefox, and Chrome. I believe VS2010 is doing something?

I have been working with for some time now. I believe that I am not thinking, which it probably is something very simple.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
deDogs

Comment: When running in IE and Firefox have you done a "view source" to verify that both browsers have the most current version of your web page?  In other words, are you sure that neither IE or Firefox have cached an older page?

Comment: are you using the visual studio web server?

Comment: Hello yes, using IE9 developer tools, I cleared the cache. Refreshed and insured that the most current page is being displayed via view source. However, why would it work outside of VS2010 and not work when running under the ASP.Net Development Server? The problem seems only when testing under IE9 and Firefox. I just tested under Opera and it was successful.???? Could be a setting?

Comment: If the videos load fine when viewing the page locally, not through a web server then this may be a mime type issue with IIS or ASP.Net Development Server. Not sure if you can configure mime types on ASP.Net Development Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After returning to this project, I found the answer to why HTML Videos were missing.

My findings can be read at my blog: [Visual Studio Development Web Server, mp4 isn’t part of the set of built in known Mime types.](http://idedogs.blogspot.com/2012/07/visual-studio-development-web-server.html)

Thank you,
deDogs

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the people in the comments that it might be an ASP.NET Development Server issue.  Try two things:  Publish the site to a legitimate local web server and try to open it from there.  Also, for the dev server see if adding "~/" to the front of your urls helps anything.